# How do I remove all of the pages only the top toolbar in Magento

Tags: magento

How do I remove all of the pages only on the top toolbar (Toolbar 1) in Magento?

Comment: Did you tried something yet ? If yes, please provide what. Stack Overflow is not intended to do the things for you but instead to help you when problem / bugs... occur. Maybe this question is best suited for http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by modifying catalog/product/list.phtml and catalog/prodct/list/toolbar.phtml from your theme.

First, the changes in catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml.
Wrap the div with class pager in this if statement (the full div element not just the tag opening line):

```
<?php if (!$this->getHidePager()) : ?>
   <!-- <div class="pager"> here -->
<?php endif;?>
```

now in catalog/product/list.phtml replace this line at the top of the file:

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

with this one:

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarBlock()->setHidePager(true)->toHtml();?>
```

and the same line at the bottom of the file with this one:

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarBlock()->setHidePager(false)->toHtml();?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to change top toolbar template from product listing.

Instead of:`<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>`

Replace it with this:`<?php echo  $this->getToolbarBlock()->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar-top.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>`

Create new template as `toolbar-top.phtml` and comment pager code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Both the toolbars are coming from same Phtml file : catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml.

In your list.phtml, there are two calls for

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

You can remove any of the one to remove.

If you want to have different toolbars for both up and bottom, replicate toolbar.phtml to toolbarup.phtml & toolbarbottom.phtml. DO the changes as you wish and replace the toolbar.phtml in layout/catalog.xml with 2 entries of your custom toolbars.

Comment: Also, you need to replce the getchildhtml in list.phtml to call your custom toolbars in it.